# Creating instance of class accessor

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am currently writing a unit test framework which shall in the end run standard unit tests written in Visual Studio. The Framework is currently not working correctly with accessors. Consider the following test method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestMethod()
{
      ExampleMethods_Accessor target = null;
      target = new ExampleMethods_Accessor();
      target.SomeMethod();
}
```

In this example, the accessor has been generated by Visual Studio. The unit test works perfectly fine when run using the Unit Testing environment of Visual Studio. However, I would like to invoke the TestMethod() from within my Framework. At the line "target = new ExampleMethods_Accessor()", the following exception is thrown:

The type initializer for "Proband.ExampleMethods_Accessor" threw an excepition.

Inner exception:

Could not load file or assembly: Proband, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null...

Has anyone an idea of how the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework invokes unit tests? I was thinking it might be due to the missing TestContext object. This is "null" in my case. When starting the unit test in Visual Studio, the TestContext object contains a lot of information. Could it be, that I need to initialize it properly? How would it need to be initialized?

Thanks for all help,
Christian

**EDIT:**

I kept experimenting with the way accessors are working. I used ILSpy to see what code is being generated into the Proband_Accessor.dll. It turns out that the instruction causing the exception is:

```
SomeClass_Accessor.m_privateType = new PrivateType("Probant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "Probant.SomeClass");
```

I modified my unit test code to be like this (just for test):

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("Proband.dll")]
    public void SomeMethodTest()
    {
        ExampleMethods_Accessor target = null;
        ExampleMethods c = null;

        try
        {
            Assembly.Load("Proband, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"); // this works fine
            PrivateType tx = new PrivateType(typeof(ExampleMethods)); // this works fine as well (also without loading the assembly)

            PrivateType t = new PrivateType("Proband, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "Proband.ExampleMethods"); // this causes the exception

            c = new ExampleMethods(); // this works fine
            target = new ExampleMethods_Accessor(); // this causes the exception as well
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int actual;
        actual = target.SomeMethod();
    }
```

I do absolutely not understand, why "new PrivateType("Proband, Version...." does not work. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: What is the `Proband` assembly, and how have you *tried* to make it available?

Comment: what exactly are you writing? it seems like you are using the MSTest framework, from your use of [TestMethod]. Are you writing some kind of custom test _runner_?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for not explaining: The proband assembly is the one containing the code that should be tested. ExampleMethods is a class inside the proband assembly, that contains the private methods ("SomeMethod").

Comment: @Adam ralph - I am writing an "add-on" for the MSTest framework. Before executing the unit test, I am creating mutations of the code under test and performing mutation testing. This works very well unless you need to use accessors.

Comment: Interesting. Mutation testing is something which is rather lacking in the .NET toolspace. Have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163619.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, I have actually read this article. My framework uses similar techniques for assembling and disassembling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to create a workaround for the issue.

To my AppDomain, I am adding an AssemblyResolveEventHandler:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
```

This event handler contains the following code:

```
    private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Name == "Proband, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
        {
            // resolving correct assembly of type under test
            return typeof(ExampleMethods).Assembly;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now the line of code "target = new ExampleMethods_Accessor();" works fine and returns the correct accessor object.

I still do not understand, why the Assembly cannot be resolved automatically.

Even if it is very unlikely that anyone will have the same problem: I hope this answer helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not doing anything nearly as complex, but I had:

1. web application project using .NET 3.5
2. Configuration project using .NET 3.5
3. Test project using .NET 3.5

I was getting the same BadImageFormat exception when trying to run a unit test using an accessor.

I found the following link:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677203/even-after-installing-vs2010-sp1-unit-tests-targeting-3-5-framework-fail-if-they-are-using-private-accessor#details

The second work-around solved my problem.  I changed the test project to target .NET 4.0 and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will try this with .NET 4.0 test assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact problem, and it was because I removed the `DeploymentItem` attribute from the test method. Once I added it again, I no longer got the error on the build machine.

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("FedImportServer.dll")]  // ** This is necessary for the build machine. **
public void SourceFileStillExistsAfterProcessingFails()
```

Note: I never got the error when running it locally.

This is the error:

`Test method FedImportTests.FedImportServiceHostTest.FileNoLongerExistsAfterSucessfulProcessing threw exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'FedImportServer.Processing.FileProcessor_Accessor' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FedImportServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`